# ConnectionLimit in Grizzly HttpServer

Tags: java, http, grizzly, httpserver

How can I set or increase the connection limit or the max. pool size of worker threads in a grizzly `HttpServer` which i created with:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(host, port);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no configuration for limiting the number of concurrent connections. 
In order to tweak the kernel or worker thread pools, you'll need to get a hold of the transport.

```
HttpServer server = ...
// The default network listener is named grizzly when 
// creating a server via the factory method
NetworkListener l = server.getNetworkListener("grizzly");
TCPNIOTransport transport = l.getTransport();

// You can make changes to the kernel thread pool
// by calling transport.getKernelThreadPoolConfig().
// Changes to the worker thread pool via
// transport.getWorkerThreadPoolConfig().
```

Java docs for the above can be found [here](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/)

If you do need to be able to limit the number of concurrent connections, I'd recommend following up on the Grizzly user's mailing [list](https://grizzly.java.net/mailing.html)